# How do I get vim-gnome on Mac to enable copying to clipboard?

Tags: vim

I am trying to enable copying to clipboard on mac using vim. Apparently vim normally does not come with this feature (and vim-gnome does). How do I get vim-gnome for mac to enable copying to clipboard?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

how about macvim instead of vim-gnome?

```
brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

Or if you don't want that, the vim in brew has clipboard support:

```
brew update
brew install vim --with-client-server
```